# send ajax jquery request show response into dialog jqueryui

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

i have link like this
i need show detail of city in dialog box with city id or name but cannot send data

```
<a class="dot"  style="top:110px;  left:145px;" continent="NA"  id="1"  name="1"></a>
```

i need when clicked show the popup dialog 
but dialog not open after click

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('a.dot').click(function(){
var vid=$(this).attr('id');
var vname=$(this).attr('name');
var vcity=$(this).attr('city');
$.ajax({
type : GET,
data:{id : vid , name : vname , city : vcity},
url : "ajax.php",
success : function(data){
$('#dialog-message').html(data);
}

});
});
</script>

<a class="dot" style="top:110px; left:145px;" continent="NA" id="1" name="1" city="teh"></a>

<div id="dialog-message">
</div>
```

And ajax.php code is:

```
if(isset($_GET)){
echo '<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div id="dialog-message">
   ' . $_GET[name]  . ',' . $_GET[id] . ',' . $_GET[city] . '
    </div>
';
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors returned from either PHP or JavaScript? Also, what is drawn in the `<div id="dialog-message">` so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.dot').click(function(){
    var vid=$(this).attr('id');
    var vname=$(this).attr('name');
    var vcity=$(this).attr('city');
    $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    data:{id : vid , name : vname , city : vcity},
    url : "ajax.php",
    success : function(data){
    $('#dialog-message').html(data);
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog();
    }

    });
    });
    });
```

type:"GET" NOT type:GET

ajax.php

```
if(isset($_GET)){
echo  $_GET[name]  . ',' . $_GET[id] . ',' . $_GET[city] ;
}
```

Comment: your ajax is working perfect now see console.add alert(data); before $('#dialog-message').html(data);

Comment: you also have to show the div the using $('#dialog-message').show();

Comment: when i use alert before than  $('#dialog-message').html(data); show the true but problem is not show jqueryui dialog?! how to can fix ? how can show data in jqueryui dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code seems to be creating a `<div id="dialog-message">` inside of another `<div id="dialog-message">`.  Try changing the `id` of what your PHP produces, and change the script within the PHP to match the new `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax .get can do the job so easy:

```
//This is a Click even. It fires when you click the (<a class="dot">CLick</a>)
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.dot').click(function(){

var vid=$(this).attr('id');

var vname=$(this).attr('name');

var vcity=$(this).attr('city');

$.get("ajax.php?id="+ vid +"&name="+ vname + "&city=" + vcity, function(data){

    $('#dialog-message').html(data);

    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({

            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
});

</script>



//This is a load even. It fires when the page is loaded
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

var vid=$(this).attr('id');

var vname=$(this).attr('name');

var vcity=$(this).attr('city');

$.get("ajax.php?id="+ vid +"&name="+ vname + "&city=" + vcity, function(data){

    $('#dialog-message').html(data);

    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({

            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

    });

});

</script>

    <a class="dot" style="top:110px; left:145px;" continent="NA" id="1" name="1" city="teh">Click Here</a>

    <div id="dialog-message" style="display:none;">
    </div>
```

ajax.php

```
if(isset($_GET)){
echo  $_GET[name]  . ',' . $_GET[id] . ',' . $_GET[city] ;
}
```

Comment: I inspected ur code and u have done many mistakes. you need to decide how u want to triger the event. Check my code and you will see the 2 types of event u can use.

Comment: I edited my code. you should use only one. you have used both in your code.